# Configure statsd to work with Graphite

Tags: python, ubuntu, graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

So, I want to install statsd and use client python-statsd to collect some data for my Graphite that is successfully installed on my system. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04), but still have no statsd subdirectory in my Graphite folder[image: only carbon subfolder]

So what might be wrong and how I can check statsd working? (my python-statsd client doesn't show any error messages)

Comment: the same when configuring collectd ([tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-collectd-to-gather-system-metrics-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04)). Still no subcategories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statsd must know where the carbon-cache (or carbon-relay) is located, it's part of the tutorial you followed. This should go into to the configuration for statsd.

```
{
graphitePort: 2003,
graphiteHost: "127.0.0.1",
port: 8125
}
```

To test that carbon-cache works you can send a message with echo

```
echo "foo.bar 1 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 <graphite host> 2003
```

this should give you a directory **foo** with a metric **bar** and value **1**.

If that works, then your carbon is correctly configured and reachable. The next test it to talk to statsd

```
echo "foo.bar:2|c" | nc -q0 -u <statsd host> 8125
```

that should give you a new value of **2** in **foo.bar**. If that works then all should work.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in improper configuration of carbon-cache and after I double-checked it, all works fine.